# Mojito - Load NodeJS Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, yui, mojito

I'm using :

- Mojito 0.5.5
- NPM 1.2.14
- NodeJS 0.8.22

I'm trying to create a simple Mojito application using NodeJS modules, packaged with NPM.

[Documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/docs/topics/mojito_npm.html) say that :

- Create a Mojito application.
- Add any needed dependencies to dependencies object in package.json.
- Install dependencies with npm: {app_dir}$ npm install
- When Mojito starts, your application will have access to the installed npm modules.

Indeed, the example above isn't working.

```
"dependencies": {
    "mojito": "0.5.x",
    "async": "0.2.x"
},

status: function(ac) {
    var async = require('async');
    ac.done({
        status: 'loaded'
    });
}
```

Mojito server : "Error: Cannot find module 'async'"

Web page error : "Error: MODULE_NOT_FOUND"

Any clue ?

PS : Of course, after **npm install**, the project folder have a **node_modules** folder with the **async** package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As today, `mojito` npm package is used as a cli but it also holds the mojito core. This is problematic because most developers will run the app by doing `mojito start`, which runs from the global `mojito` package. This, plus the fact that the current YUI is messing with the `require`, it causes a lot of troubles when requiring dependencies.

The solution is simple, make sure you install mojito locally in your application, and run the app by doing `./node_modules/mojito/bin/mojito start` or by doing `node server.js` instead of `mojito start`.

Aside from that, we are working on splitting the cli and core into separate packages, and waiting for `YUI 3.9.0` to solve this problem once for all so developers can keep using `mojito start`.